# How can EmptyResultDataAccessException be thrown?

Tags: java, database, spring, exception, jdbc

I have the following method in my DAO implementation:

```
@Override
public String getResultEntry(String arg1, String key, String date) throws SQLException, IOException {
    String res = "";
    String sql = buildSQL(arg1, key, date);

    MapSqlParameterSource namedParameters = new MapSqlParameterSource();
    namedParameters.addValue("arg1", arg1);
    namedParameters.addValue("id", key);
    namedParameters.addValue("date", date);

    try {
        logger.info("getResultEntry is about to execute the following query:[" + sql + "]");

        Blob blob = namedParameterJdbcTemplate.queryForObject(sql, namedParameters, Blob.class);
        long blobLength = blob.length();
        byte[] bytes = blob.getBytes(1, (int)blobLength);

        logger.info("getResultEntry END");

        res = convertBytesToString(bytes);

    } catch (EmptyResultDataAccessException erdae) {
        logger.error("getResultEntry failed to execute the query due to exception! Return an empty string ", erdae);
        logger.info("getResultEntry END");

        res = "";
    }
    return res;

}
```

sometimes the query returns empty result and the `EmptyResultDataAccessException` is thrown. I am catching it and return an empty string. However, I keep seeing the exception and afterwards the execution is terminated.

The exception:

```
org.springframework.dao.EmptyResultDataAccessException: Incorrect result size: expected 1, actual 0
at org.springframework.dao.support.DataAccessUtils.requiredSingleResult(DataAccessUtils.java:71)
at org.springframework.jdbc.core.namedparam.NamedParameterJdbcTemplate.queryForObject(NamedParameterJdbcTemplate.java:179)
at org.springframework.jdbc.core.namedparam.NamedParameterJdbcTemplate.queryForObject(NamedParameterJdbcTemplate.java:191)
at com.ars.linking.mrretriever.dao.MRRetrieverDAOImpl.getResultEntry(MRRetrieverDAOImpl.java:82)
at com.ars.linking.mrretriever.exec.MRRetriver.processResults(MRRetriver.java:125)
at com.ars.linking.mrretriever.exec.MRRetriver.main(MRRetriver.java:81)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:616)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.jarinjarloader.JarRsrcLoader.main(JarRsrcLoader.java:58)
```

What should I do to "properly" handle the exception? (I am not interested to rethrow it just swallow it and return an empty string)

Comment: If I am not wrong, you are currently doing the same.Isn't it? You have catched that exception and you are not letting it reach the previous layer.What else do you want to achieve?

Comment: just remove the stack Trace if you don't want to print it.

Comment: I see that the Exception somehow sneaks in and terminates the flow. I fail to understand how can it happen (I swallow it).

Answer (score 1):

You are explicitly logging the exception:

```
logger.error("getResultEntry failed to execute the query due to exception! Return an empty string ", erdae);
```

Remove the second argument if you don't want to see the stacktrace in the log. Better, remove the whole line because this is not an error and you already have an `info` log entry.

The execution of your code is not terminated by this exception. Find the cause of termination, which lies elsewhere and may or may not be related to the empty string you are returning.

Comment: logging the exception should not terminate the execution.

Comment: @BorisTreukhov aviad was commenting on an earlier version of my answer that didn't provide an explanation for his observed behavior, which is that the execution terminates.

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik ok, that's great ))